# How to display only 10 page numbers and first and last buttons in Angular pagination

Tags: angular, pagination

I'm trying to display only 10 page numbers and include first and last buttons instead of all the possible ones.

My code :

```
<nav aria-label="...">
    <ul style="margin-left: 180px;margin-top:-10px;" class="pagination"  *ngIf="phoneNumberPage?.content" >
      <li *ngFor="let page of ' '.repeat(phoneNumberPage.totalPages).split(''), let i = index " (click)="getPageClient(i)" [class.active]="i === selectedPage" class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">{{i}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Here is how it comes :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

What change should i make to make it look something like:

```
  First 1 2 3 4 5...Last
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are a lot of missing work if you want to create your own paginator. I will not write the finished code for you, but I can add some pointers to get you going.

First, you could hardcode the `First` and `Last` buttons, and also add some display conditions (e.g. if you are on the first page, don't show `First`)

You can add a conditional to your anchor tag, (e.g. `<a *ngIf="index < 10">`) Of course, you need to add extra logic to your display condition based on which page the user is on. Maybe you could store an extra variable: `currentPage` in your component, and then you could start the *ngFor from the currentPage.